# "Energy transfer" and "Energy transport"

Tags: energy, terminology

Are the terms "energy transfer" and "energy transport" sometimes or always interchangeable?

My own surmise is that the term "energy transfer" is slightly more general: "energy transport" refers to *spatial* transport of energy (e.g. via conduction or convection), while "energy transfer" also include a transfer of energy in the same position, e.g. between electrons and phonons in a metal.

Comment: That works. Terms like that are best defined when used to clear up any confusion, since there is some variation in how terms are used, though hopefully a consensus is formed on meanings. Though even if there is a generally agreed upon term, someone can publish something using the term in another way, so one has to deal with that definition in that case if they ever reference it. For example. I've seen 'dynamic range' and 'signal to noise ratio' mixed up. All you can do is hope they make it clear what they mean in each scenario, if there is confusion.

Comment: That being said, I would argue that a clear definition for all scenarios cannot truly be given. So there is no absolute answer.

Answer (score 1):

Energy transfer and energy transport are two different things.

Energy transport means moving energy from one location to another.

Energy transfer means moving energy out of something (solid, liquid or gas) thereby reducing its energy, into something  else (another solid, liquid or gas) thereby increasing its energy. The two mechanisms of energy transfer are heat and work.

In order for energy transfer to occur, it is sometimes necessary to transport energy from the location from which it is taken from something, to the location at which something else absorbs it.

Take heat transfer by radiation. Energy is transported from the location of the radiation emitting object by electromagnetic waves (or photons if you will) to the location of the radiation absorbing object. But until energy is actually absorbed at the location of the receiver, it is not "transferred". If the transport occurs in a vacuum, no energy is transferred in the vacuum itself.

On the other hand, take heat transfer by conduction. The two objects need to be in contact with one another. Energy transfer (transfer of kinetic energy from the higher temperature object to the lower temperature object) occurs at the same location, namely at the interface of the contacting surfaces. There was no need to "transport" the energy between two different locations.

Another example of energy transport is a moving mass that goes from one location to another with respect to some frame of reference. The mass has kinetic energy due to its motion. When it moves from one location to another its macroscopic kinetic energy is transported with it from one location to another. So is its microscopic (internal) kinetic energy. But none of its kinetic energy has been transferred to something else at the second location until and unless it interacts with that something else, and either does work on that something else, or transfers heat to or from that something else.

The last example shows that energy can be “transported” without necessarily being “transferred”.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's good people want to have settled meanings for terms, but if you look up energy transfer online, you get: 

energy transfer

    n.
    The conversion of one form of energy into another, or the movement of energy from one place to another.

Comment: Which sounds more like the definition in the question given. Along with that I don't know many that would argue energy conversion is included in energy transport.

Comment: @user47014 In my experience, especially working in the area of developing technical standards. I've learned that agreeing on definitions can be a futile exercise. I think the term "energy transport" can mean many things, particularly on how one "defines" transport. But I do believe that the term "energy transfer" has a definite meaning in physics, particularly thermodynamics, and it is synonymous with the terms heat and work, the mechanisms by which energy can be transferred between a system and its surroundings. It is not energy conversion. That happens after the transfer.

Comment: @user47014  But energy "transport", that is, the movement of energy from one location to another need not involve any energy "transfer". For example, a photon moves from point A to point B in the vacuum of outer space. Its energy has been transported from A to B. But unless there is something at location B to absorb it, no transfer has occurred. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @ Bob D Should you give a disclaimer that this maybe only applies in physics or is that the expected assumption on the site?

Answer (score 0):

The definitions from Merriam-Webster show the ambiguity:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transport

- transport - to transfer or convey from one place to another

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer

- transfer - to convey from one person, place, or situation to another; to cause to pass from one to another; transform or change

Also, in engineering, transport or transfer a process of moving something (mass or energy as heat) from one place to another. We can find references on either topics that cover the same things and interchange the terminology.

Given the more expansive list of contexts in the definition of transfer compared to transport, your view that transfer is a more general term is not without some support. Considering the last form of the definition of transfer (transform or change) also allows us to recognize that energy transfer (change in form) does not need to include energy transport (convey from one place to another). Thus, one might easily propose to discuss the mechanisms of *energy transfer* from work to heat in a car engine or from vibrational modes to electronic modes in molecules but one would not propose to discuss the modes of *energy transport* in those same cases.